# Как отсортировать массив путей файлов android?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Я получаю массив файлов системы:

```
curFolder.listFiles()
```

но мне нужно отсортировать их в алфавитном порядке. Я нашел два способа: использовть встроенный фильтр и использовать Comparator. Вот к примеру использование встроенного фильтра:

```
Log.i("m", Arrays.toString(curFolder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File file, String s) {
                return file.getName();
            }
        })))
```

я получаю такой лог:

```
[/storage/emulated/0/Music, /storage/emulated/0/Podcasts, /storage/emulated/0/Ringtones, /storage/emulated/0/Alarms, /storage/emulated/0/Notifications, /storage/emulated/0/Pictures, /storage/emulated/0/Movies, /storage/emulated/0/Download, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM, /storage/emulated/0/Android, /storage/emulated/0/Jobnetzwerk]
```

я так понимаю нужно каким-то образом сравнивать имена файлов. Не могу понять что и как правильно сделать. Вообще я потом буду отправлять эти пути в адаптер recycelerView и при выборе пункта списка я буду переходить в выбранный файл/дирректорию. Как можно передать этот массив уже отсортированным так же как и имена?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему таким способом:

```
File[] files = curFolder.listFiles();

Arrays.sort(files, (f1, f2) -> {
if (f1.isDirectory() && !f2.isDirectory()) {
return -1;
} else if (!f1.isDirectory() && f2.isDirectory()) {
return 1;
} else {
return f1.compareTo(f2);
}
});
```

вроде помогло:

```
[/storage/emulated/0/Alarms, /storage/emulated/0/Android, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM, /storage/emulated/0/Download, /storage/emulated/0/Jobnetzwerk, /storage/emulated/0/Movies, /storage/emulated/0/Music, /storage/emulated/0/Notifications, /storage/emulated/0/Pictures, /storage/emulated/0/Podcasts, /storage/emulated/0/Ringtones]
```

Comment: А так не работает `Arrays.sort(files);`?

Comment: @gil9red, я же пытаюсь отправить в адаптер массив путей как File[]

Comment: Метод `sort` имеет перегрузку с массивом `Object`, у которых должен быть реализован интерфейс `Comparator`, поэтому сортировка `Arrays.sort(files);` должна работать, т.к. `File` как раз реализует `Comparator`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы получаете объекты класса `File`, то там уже реализован интерфейс `Comparable`. При том таким образом, что при сортировке методом `sort` из класса `Arrays` сравниваются именно пути.

Так, что вероятно Вам и не придётся изобретать свой "велосипед".

Подробнее можно почитать в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#compareTo(java.io.File)) и в этой [статье](http://javatutorialhq.com/java/io/file-class-tutorial/comparetofile-pathname-method-example/).

Comment: я вроде смог решить свою проблему, посмотрите если не сложно мой ответ, может чего подправите)) спасибо за ваш совет, учту :)